# how copy a list of files into a single directory

Tags: linux

I want to copy a list of files into a single directory, but make the target directory the first filename in the command, how can I do it with linux command.

Comment: The `cp` command will do what you want but the target directory must come after the souce file(s). Why do you want to change from the accepted standard? Try `man cp` for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you the command to look like the following -

> specialcopy destDir filetocopy1 filetocopy2 filetocopy3

if so, create a script called `specialcopy.sh` with below text

```
#!/bin/bash

DEST=$1
shift
cp "$@" "$DEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, there is **`cp -t`** for xargs users.

```
xargs -d'\n' cp -t targetdir < filelist
```